# When I upload/copy an image it fails, when I hit refresh/resend it works

Tags: php, image, upload, copy

Alight so, I am working on a small section of a project and I am uploading an image and then copying it to resize afterwards.  What is happening is that when I click submit to upload, it fails, but if I hit refresh/resend the info it succeeds...

```
    $uploadFile = $uploadDir . $imageName;
    $imageName2 = $front[0]."_large\.".$front[1];
    $uploadFile2 = $uploadDir . $imageName2;

        if(move_uploaded_file($imageTemp,$uploadFile))
       {
           if(!copy($uploadFile, $uploadFile2)) die("Can't copy $uploadFile2");
           }
```

What it outputs when it fails is "Can't copy         "  So, for some reason it's not getting the name of the file to be copied to until I hit refresh?

Levi

Comment: Can I see the HTML for your form and a little bit more of the PHP code?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean to escape the dot in $front[0]."_large\.".$front[1];
Were you thinking of a regular expression? if not this might be trying to save into a non existent directory.

Have you tried uploading another file, can you print_r() the $_FILES array, i've been stuck before figuring out why the $_FILES array is empty and there is no multipart form data in my form tag or the image has been corrupt and the upload stream cut by php.

Answer (score 0):

Below working fine for me;

HTML File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Stack HTML</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../repo/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form method="post" action="resize.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="image" />
            <input type="submit" name="add" value="Add" />
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

resize.php

```
<?php
    $uploadDir = 'uploads/';
    $uploadLargeDir = 'uploads/large/';

    $imageName = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $imageTemp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $uploadFile = $uploadDir . $imageName;


    if(move_uploaded_file($imageTemp,$uploadFile)) {
        $front = explode('.', $imageName);
        $imageName2 = $front[0]."_large.".$front[1];
        $uploadFile2 = $uploadLargeDir . $imageName;
         if(!copy($uploadFile, $uploadFile2)) {
            die("Can't copy $uploadFile2");
         } else {
            die('Levi! Success');
         }
    }
?>
```